# call macro twice in foreach call in Make

Tags: foreach, makefile, macros

I have a macro that calls a target for each seed:

```
define MY_MACRO
    $(foreach seed, $(shell $(SHELL_EXPORT) seq $(3) $(4)), $(eval $(call TEST_TARGET_MACRO, $(1), $(2), $(seed), FIRST_TARGET_NAME)))
endef
```

Is there a way I can call two different targets, one followed by the other? This one calls my FIRST_TARGET_NAME for every seed with the TEST_TARGET_MACRO.

Something like this...

```
define MY_MACRO
    $(foreach seed, $(shell $(SHELL_EXPORT) seq $(3) $(4)), $(eval $(call TEST_TARGET_MACRO, $(1), $(2), $(seed), FIRST_TARGET_NAME), $(call TEST_TARGET_MACRO, $(1), $(2), $(seed), SECOND_TARGET_NAME)))
endef
```

so that it will *eval* the first *call* and then the second *call* for each seed.

I couldn't seem to find a way to do this.... or find anything online

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but why can't you just write the eval/call twice?  Like this:

```
define MY_MACRO
    $(foreach seed, $(shell $(SHELL_EXPORT) seq $(3) $(4)), \
        $(eval $(call TEST_TARGET_MACRO, $(1), $(2), $(seed), FIRST_TARGET_NAME) \
        $(eval $(call TEST_TARGET_MACRO, $(1), $(2), $(seed), SECOND_TARGET_NAME))))
endef
```

Here's my simple, complete example:

```
TEST_TARGET_MACRO = all:: ; $(info 1=$1 2=$2 3=$3 4=$4)

define MY_MACRO
    $(foreach seed, $(shell seq $(3) $(4)), \
        $(eval $(call TEST_TARGET_MACRO, $(1), $(2), $(seed), FIRST_TARGET_NAME) \
        $(eval $(call TEST_TARGET_MACRO, $(1), $(2), $(seed), SECOND_TARGET_NAME))))
endef

$(call MY_MACRO,foo,bar,2,5)
```

and here's the output which is just what I'd expect:

```
1= foo 2= bar 3= 2 4= FIRST_TARGET_NAME
1= foo 2= bar 3= 2 4= SECOND_TARGET_NAME
1= foo 2= bar 3= 3 4= FIRST_TARGET_NAME
1= foo 2= bar 3= 3 4= SECOND_TARGET_NAME
1= foo 2= bar 3= 4 4= FIRST_TARGET_NAME
1= foo 2= bar 3= 4 4= SECOND_TARGET_NAME
1= foo 2= bar 3= 5 4= FIRST_TARGET_NAME
1= foo 2= bar 3= 5 4= SECOND_TARGET_NAME
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

Comment: This is what I want to do, and I tried this, but it seems like only the FIRST_TARGET_NAME is being called and not the SECOND_TARGET_NAME.

Comment: Well, you'll have to provide a SSCCE http://sscce.org/ then because I created a sample makefile here with a simple definition for TEST_TARGET_MACRO and it worked just as I'd expect.